# Got a BIOS message telling of SATA port 5 failure. How to tell which drive that was in Windows 7?

Tags: ssd, sata

Got a BIOS message telling of SATA port 5 failure (some time after plugging a new healthy SSD into a 4-5 year old PC). How to tell which drive that was in Windows 7? The largest Channel number in drive Hardware tab is Channel 4, and occupied by the SSD.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to tell. You can assign any drive letter to any drive connect to any port. One of those situations you can tell by simply finding which drive is missing.

Comment: Well, I don't know if it's anywhere easy to get this info programmatically from Windows, but BIOS itself confirmed my suspicions. The SSD was at Channel 4 there as well and it couldn't initialize properly. Maybe a BIOS update is due.